# How do I make this code work as though the else statement is inexistent when an if is correct, and equally do the same for the else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

```
let all = ['Nkechi', 'Añuli', 'Nneka'];

function start(){
  let begin = prompt('Name');
  let counted = "";
  for(let i = 0; i<all.length; i++){
    if(begin === all[i]){
      counted = all[i];
      alert(`Welcome ${counted}`);
    } else {
      alert('Entrance denied');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. If condition to if is truthy, then the else branch won't be evaluated. And vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the `if else`  check in the loop do

1. Use `break;` at the end of if statement to break out of the loop once you found the name in `all` array
2. Change `else` to `else if (i === all.length - 1)` **i.e** you reached the end of the array.

```
let all = ['Nkechi', 'Añuli', 'Nneka'];

function start(){
  let begin = prompt('Name');
  let counted = "";
  for(let i = 0; i<all.length; i++){
    if(begin === all[i]){
      counted = all[i];
      alert(`Welcome ${counted}`);
      break; // break here
    } else if (i === all.length - 1) { // change else
      alert('Entrance denied');
    }
  }
}
```

But you can simplify this logic by either

1. Breaking out of the loop using `break;` once you found the name from `all` array and do else check later

OR

2. Finishing your loop first and do the `if else` check finally at the
   bottom like below.

```
    let all = ['Nkechi', 'Añuli', 'Nneka'];
    
    function start(){
      let begin = prompt('Name');
      let counted = "";
      for(let i = 0; i<all.length; i++){
        if(begin === all[i]){
          counted = all[i];
        }
      }
      if (counted === "") {
        alert('Entrance denied');
      } else {
         alert(`Welcome ${counted}`);
      }
    }
```

You can simplify all of this even more without any loop using `Array.includes` as follows

```
    const all = ['Nkechi', 'Añuli', 'Nneka'];
    function start() {
      const begin = prompt('Name');
      if (all.includes(begin)) {
         alert(`Welcome ${begin}`);
      } else {
         alert('Entrance denied');
      }
    }
```